# List_Display no Django/Python

Tags: python, django, formulário

[image: Quero Remover o Item preço de venda dessa área...]

[image: Mas sem que ele seja removido dessa outra]sXDw.png

[image: Quero remover o item preço de venda]

Minha classe Models tá assim

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    NomeRazao =    models.CharField('Nome',max_length=50,unique=False,blank=False)
    CpfCnpj = models.IntegerField('Quantidade',blank=False)
    Telefone = models.FloatField('Preço de Compra',blank=False)
    Total = models.IntegerField('Preço de Venda',blank=False)`
```

e a Admin assim

```
class ProdutoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('NomeRazao','CpfCnpj','InscEstadual','Total')
    search_fields = ('NomeRazao',)
    ordering = ('NomeRazao',)
    exclude =('Usuario',)
```

Comment: Só quero remover Item Preço de venda da lista de cadastro sem apagar ela da lista de cadastrados

Comment: Tentei ajudar editando sua msg, mas seus links para as imagens estão quebrados, tá bem confuso, tente consertar.

Comment: Você quer customizar a janela da interface de administração para não exibir determinados campos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você está querendo campos específicos no form, se for isso você tem que usar `fields` e não `list_display`

Aqui apenas name e title serão exibidos no form

#### models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=3)
        birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

#### admin.py

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'title')
```